# ASP.NET MVC 3 Edit Collection In Model In Same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple question.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class AddEditChildProductModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Sku {get;set;}
    ........
    public IEnumerable<AddEditPriceTierModel> PriceTiers {get;set;}
}
public class AddEditPriceTierModel
{
    public int QtyStart {get;set;}
    public int QtyEnd {get;set;}
    ........
}
```

My question is how do I edit the collection in the same view?

It would seem this would be very simple, maybe I am missing something.

Thanks!!

**Edit**

OK, so I used EditorTemplates, but now I am getting the following error:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

This is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult EditChildProduct(AddEditChildProductModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return PartialView("AddEditChildProduct", model);

            ChildProduct childProduct = productService.GetChildProductByID(model.ID);
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<AddEditChildProductModel, ChildProduct>(model, childProduct);
            foreach (var tier in childProduct.PriceTiers)
            {
                tier.ChildProduct = childProduct;
            }
            UnitOfWork.Commit();

            return ListChildProducts(model.ProductID);
        }
```

Shouldn't this work, as I get the `ChildProduct` with the related `PriceTiers` collection and use AutoMapper to map the differences? I maintain hidden fields for the PK and FK fields on the `PriceTier`.

I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use editor templates:

```
@model AddEditChildProductModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Sku)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sku)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Sku)
    </div>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>QtyStart</th>
                <th>QtyEnd</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PriceTiers)
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
}
```

and then define the editor template which will be rendered for each element of the `PriceTiers` list (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AddEditPriceTierModel.cshtml`) - the name and location of the editor template is important. You could also put it in `~/Views/SomeController/EditorTemplates/AddEditPriceTierModel.cshtml` if the editor template is specific only for a given controller:

```
@model AddEditPriceTierModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.QtyStart)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.QtyStart)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.QtyStart)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.QtyEnd)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.QtyEnd)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.QtyEnd)
    </td>
</tr>
```

and now your POST controller action signature will look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(AddEditChildProductModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would you look at my edit above and see if you can help me? Thanks!!

Comment: @Sam Striano, oh that seems to be some EF related stuff. I don't use EF and cannot help you as I am not an expert in the field. This question is no longer related to ASP.NET MVC 3 which is the topic of your question but related to some data access technology that you are using.

Answer (score 6):

You can fins in [Phil Haack's article "Model Binding To A List"](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) useful information about binding collections of Entities to a view.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyCollection.Count; i++)
{                    
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title) 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Author) 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].DatePublished) 
}


public ActionResult UpdateStuff(MyViewModel vm)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can find solution provided by Steven Sanderson at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/. Helped me a lot.